# Calculate NPS score by attribute using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, daxstudio

I have below columns:

ID 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4...

Attribute (4 attributes)

Online booking,
In flight wifi Service
Services in the plane
Cleanliness
Value
4
5
6
...,

Customer type:
first time
returned

I would like to calculate NPS score and visualize it in a stacked bar chart as a tooltip.

It shows me the same NPS score for each attribute, for each areas (Passives, Detractors and Promoters).
How can I solve this?

I have below:

```
Passives = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    Satisfaction[Value] = 3,
    Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time"
    )

Detractors = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    Satisfaction[Value] >= 1,
    Satisfaction[Value] <= 2,
    Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time"
 )

Promoters = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    Satisfaction[Value] >= 4,
    Satisfaction[Value] <= 5,
    Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time")

NPS Score:
NPS by attribute Score = 
var CurrentAttribute = SELECTEDVALUE(Satisfaction[Attribute])

var TotalResponses = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction,
    Satisfaction[Attribute])
)
var PromotersCount = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    Satisfaction[Value] >= 4, 
    Satisfaction[Value] <= 5, 
    Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time", 
    ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction,
    Satisfaction[Attribute]
))

var DetractorCount = CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
    Satisfaction[Value] >= 1,
    Satisfaction[Value] <= 2,
    Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time",
    ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction,
    Satisfaction[Attribute]
    ))

var PromoterPercentage = DIVIDE(PromotersCount, TotalResponses, 0)
VAR DetractorPercentage = DIVIDE(DetractorCount, TotalResponses, 0)
RETURN
(PromoterPercentage - DetractorPercentage) * 100
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Different scores for each bar (Detractor, Promoter)

This is what I have:
Same score for each bar -> something is wrong

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the calculation of the NPS score isn't filtering by each attribute, so you're seeing the overall NPS score for all attributes combined instead of for each individual attribute. Let's address this.

So,you need to apply the correct filter context for each attribute when calculating the NPS score.

```
NPS by attribute Score = 
    var CurrentAttribute = SELECTEDVALUE(Satisfaction[Attribute])
    
    var TotalResponses = CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
        ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction, Satisfaction[Attribute]),
        Satisfaction[Attribute] = CurrentAttribute
    )
    
    var PromotersCount = CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
        Satisfaction[Value] >= 4, 
        Satisfaction[Value] <= 5, 
        Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time", 
        ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction, Satisfaction[Attribute]),
        Satisfaction[Attribute] = CurrentAttribute
    )
    
    var DetractorCount = CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(Satisfaction),
        Satisfaction[Value] >= 1,
        Satisfaction[Value] <= 2,
        Satisfaction[Customer type] = "First-time",
        ALLEXCEPT(Satisfaction, Satisfaction[Attribute]),
        Satisfaction[Attribute] = CurrentAttribute
        )
    
    var PromoterPercentage = DIVIDE(PromotersCount, TotalResponses, 0)
    VAR DetractorPercentage = DIVIDE(DetractorCount, TotalResponses, 0)
    RETURN
    (PromoterPercentage - DetractorPercentage) * 100
```